# How to get yarn install --offline with node-sass working?

Tags: sass, yarnpkg, node-sass

I am trying to use `yarn` in offline mode because the build server I am using does not have access to `yarn` registry or `github.com`.

I found this [article](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/) on how to use `yarn` in offline mode which works great until I added node-sass.

It appears even if you use `yarn install --offline`, `node-sass` will go to `github.com` to download `libsass`.

Is there a way to instruct `node-sass` to use an offline version of `libsass` instead of going to `github.com`?

Comment: Presumably, as with `npm`, you can provide the `--sass-binary-site`: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Checking it out now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It worked.  Not sure how I answer this question as answered?

Comment: You can write an answer below explaining what you did to fix it, then accept it yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, you need to use either `--sass-binary-site`, `--sass-binary-name` or `--sass-binary-path` to to tell node-sass where to find `libsass`.  In my case I ended up using `sass-binary-path`.

So the first thing I did was download the `Windows` version of `libsass` [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases). I downloaded the `_binding.node` version because I assumed the `_binding.pdb` version is a debugging file.

I my case I created a `.yarnrc` that looks like the below:

```
yarn-offline-mirror "////sharedrive//folder"
yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true
sass-binary-path "////sharedrive//folder//win32-ia32-47_binding.node"
```

With the `Windows` version all `/` needed to be escaped with `//`. `sass-binary-path` needed the `libsass` binary at the end which in the above case is `win32-ia32-47_binding.node`.

So with all that everything worked great.

Comment: This is also an extremely useful method of avoiding the CONSTANT rebuilding of `node-sass` whenever you use `yarn` or `npm i`.

Comment: I'll reiterate Troy's point... anyone knows successful dev orgs need fast build times. `node-sass` developers should not be trying to modify the layout of system libraries. `yarn` seems to be built in a way that forces the ecosystem to leave behind artifacts such as these... where scripts download arbitrary binaries from the internet during the install phase .....

Comment: `apk add --no-cache libsass` is the way to go if you're using an alpine based Docker image for node